# Webdriver : ChromeDriver : Accessing From Within Framework Jar File

Tags: java, maven, selenium, webdriver

I am developing a framework using selenium webdriver in Java. I have two maven projects. One is for the framework and other is for the test project.

In order to launch launch ChromeDriver, I need to set the system property with the path of the chromedriver.exe file. I am doing this in DriverFactory.java which is in /src/main/java of the Framework Project. Now, if I place the exe files in src/main/resources/drivers, Java complains that the file is not found. The code is :

```
private static String chromeDriverLocation = "drivers/chromedriver.exe";
File cDriver = new File(DriverFactory.class.getResource(chromeDriverLocation).getFile());
// Is it executable
  if (!cDriver.canExecute()) {
     cDriver.setExecutable(true);
  }
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", DriverFactory.class.getResource(chromeDriverLocation).getFile());
```

I tried placing this file in src/main/resources/drivers in the Test Project and modified the code like :

```
private static String chromeDriverLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\classes\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverLocation);
```

Though the above piece of code works in local when executed through Jenkins(Maven), I am not sure if this is the best way. Can someone suggest other good ways of achieving this ?

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you may place the chromedriver.exe file into a directory added to `PATH`. In this case running the ChromeDriver will be as simple as creating an instance of `new ChromeDriver()` without dealing with system properties.

If you still would like to store chromedriver.exe under Resources, you may get it as steam, save to a file and set the "webdriver.chrome.driver" property:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("chromedriver.exe");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("chromedriver.exe");
IOUtils.copy(in, out);
```